# .gitignore com .env

Tags: git

Adicionei um .env ao meu arquivo .gitignore. Mas quando altero alguma coisa no .env, as alterações estão subindo junto no commit.

Segue o meu .gitignore:

```
# Logs
logs
*.log
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
# Runtime data
pids
*.pid
*.seed
*.pid.lock


# Directory for instrumented libs generated by jscoverage/JSCover
lib-cov

# Coverage directory used by tools like istanbul
coverage

# nyc test coverage
.nyc_output

# Grunt intermediate storage (http://gruntjs.com/creating-plugins#storing-task-files)
.grunt

# Bower dependency directory (https://bower.io/)
bower_components

# node-waf configuration
.lock-wscript

# Compiled binary addons (https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html)
build/Release

# Dependency directories
node_modules/
jspm_packages/

# Typescript v1 declaration files
typings/

# Optional npm cache directory
.npm

# Optional eslint cache
.eslintcache

# Optional REPL history
.node_repl_history

# Output of 'npm pack'
*.tgz

# Yarn Integrity file
.yarn-integrity

.env
```

Já tentei adicionar diretamente pela opção do VSCode, mas não rolou. Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Tenta esses comandos `git clean -n -xf` e depois `git clean -xf`.

Comment: Valeu pelo apoio, mas não funcionou ainda.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Execute `git rm --cached ./seuarquivo.txt` para remover o arquivo da árvore de trabalho e do índice do git, mas mantê-lo no seu sistema local.

Se você edita o `.gitignore` com um arquivo que já está na área de preparação (staging area), o arquivo continua sendo rastreado. Pode ler mais na documentação do Git: [`git-rm`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm) e [`--cached`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm#Documentation/git-rm.txt---cached).